# ListView cant access last element of the list

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a list of objects I want to list on the screen and im using a ListView with an adapter. And I have added a listViewItem click event like this:

```
lstViewData.ItemClick += OnListViewItemClicked;
```

The event itself:

```
    private void OnListViewItemClicked(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lstViewData.Count; i++)
        {
            if (e.Position == i)
                lstViewData.GetChildAt(i).SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Gray);
            else
                lstViewData.GetChildAt(i).SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
        }
```

The `lstViewData` has 5 elements in it. So for the purpose of the for loop means `i` goes from 0 to 4. Which it does.

The issue is once `i` gets to the last element of the list I get a error saying
Reference not set to an instance of an object. Aka nullreferenceException If I remember correctly.

I went to debugging and saw that all 5 elements of the list were not null and all was well and that the index is never out of range. So I am lost and I dont know why my code breaks when attempting to access the last element of the list.

Comment: try this in the for loop: for (int i = 0; i <= f_listView.getLastVisiblePosition() - f_listView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); i++)   (the GetChildAt(index) method can only access visible elements of the listview

Comment: @Zserbinator This helped alot, It doesnt say in the doc that if the view isnt visible that its not even referenced. So this works it does crash. but also if I scroll down and select some item the one under it is selected, bc for every child not visible from the top, I need to adjust the position by that amount. Ill try this iwht a recycler. Thanks alot for the help :D

Comment: glad I could help out

Comment: @Zserbinator You can write that "fix" as an answer and ill accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GetChildAt(index)` method can only access visible elements of the `ListView`. Try this in the for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= f_listView.getLastVisiblePosition() - f_listView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); i++)
```